Python calling another file
I need help calling a file from a Python script. The file executes some commands that I need to run from Python.
import subprocess

name = open(“filename.bat”, “r”)
subprocess.run(name)

I see no output. Nothing happens. If I do print I see the complete file but I need to execute commands it has.

Did you read the docs and look for examples of how to use subprocess? Why are you passing the return value from open to the subprocess.run function?

You seem to be looking for subprocess.run(“filename.bat”)

@tripleee when I use that it shows file not found when it’s there in same directory

Then subprocess.run(“./filename.bat”) but I suspect you are in the wrong directory. See also What exactly is current working directory?

@jarmod I am new learning python now. I did looked for examples but I see mostly for reading. I am trying to see how I can include a file that execute commands

You want to execute a batch file (filename.bat) from a Python script but currently see no output when using subprocess.run.
Instead of opening the file, pass the file name directly to subprocess.run.
To see the output, use the capture_output parameter.
import subprocess

# Execute the batch file
result = subprocess.run(["filename.bat"], capture_output=True, text=True, shell=True)

# Print the output
print(result.stdout)
print(result.stderr)

or maybe for a .bat file you should run
import subprocess

cmd1 = ['filename.bat']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd1,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = p.communicate(input='x'.encode())[0]
print(output.decode('ascii'))


Thanks for your response. I see error now OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: './filename.bat'

with shell=True, or with Popen it should work for .bat file if there is missing header in it
